# Kibana - find http-URLs

Tags: kibana

I have a field containing URLs and want to filter all URLs starting with "http://".

I'm unable to figure out how to do that.
I tried as a filter:

```
scan.domain.url : http\://*
scan.domain.url : "http\://*"
scan.domain.url : /^http\:\/\//
```

Then I also tried Query DSL

```
{
  "regexp": {
    "scan.domain.url": "^http://"
  }
}
```

I always get empty results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In elastic search regex token ^ $ are not supported.
You need to search on whole string (keyword). Text is broken in tokens so full url will not be available in elastic search.

```
GET employer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "scan.domain.url.keyword": "http://.*"
    }
  }
}
```